# Loop through opened IEs and select the IE with the TITLE or URL

Tags: excel, vba

I require the VBA to loop through already opened IEs and select the IE with the TITLE or URL. (Make the IE pop up.)

```
marker = 0

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count

For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)

    my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
    my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

    If my_title Like "Hillgate" & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
    
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
    
        marker = 1
        Exit For
    Else
    End If
Next

If marker = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("A matching webpage was found")
Else
    MsgBox ("A matching webpage was not found")
End If

IE.Visible = True
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your precise question. Does the code run? If so, what about its behaviour do you want to change?

Comment: Hithe code does run but only the visible = true does not work.  Any help.... i dont really require message box?

Answer (score 0):

I found this code a while ago and does what you need, just call it from your main function:

```
Sub Example()
Dim IE As Object
  Set IE = GetIeByTitle("Title in WebPage")
  If Not(IE Is Nothing) Then
  '... my stuff
End Sub

' ZVI:2013-03-19 Get IE object of already open window by its title
' Arguments:
'   Title     -  title of the searchied IE window
'   [IsLike]  -  False/True = exact/partial searching, default is False
'   [IsFocus] -  False/True = don't_activate/activate IE window, default is False
Function GetIeByTitle(Title, Optional IsLike As Boolean, Optional IsFocus As Boolean) As Object
  Dim w As Object
  For Each w In CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    With w
      If .Name = "Windows Internet Explorer" Then
        If IsLike Then

          If InStr(1, .locationName & " - " & .Name, Title, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            ' Partial title of window is found - activate IE window
            If IsFocus Then
              w.Visible = False
              w.Visible = True
            End If
            Set GetIeByTitle = w
            Exit For
          End If
        Else
          If StrComp(.locationName & " - " & .Name, Title) = 0 Then
            ' Title of window is found - activate IE window
            If IsFocus Then
              w.Visible = False
              w.Visible = True
            End If
            Set GetIeByTitle = w
            Exit For
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next
  Set w = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Hi  does this i need to use two diff macros?

Comment: Yes you need to call your main function to the second one "GetIeByTitle" is the one that is going to check the website, call it as in Sub example

Comment: It's really hard to explain if you don't know how macro calling works (functions or etc), please research about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function
Place on top of your subroutine

Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

In Subroutine place this

BringWindowToTop IE.hwnd